# Why do we examine the rate of convergence when we find a confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, error, convergence, estimators

> [image]

I would like to help me with this. I don't understand why do we examine the rate of convergence. Also what do we mean by saying "the error is usually dominated by the variance, not the bias"

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you understand the 'big O' notation?

Comment: Hi! I have read these notes: http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture7.pdf for the big O notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English it's saying that the mean squared error of the estimator is the sum of its variance and its squared bias.  As the sample size increases the squared bias decreases more quickly (typically) than the variance, so eventually the mean squared error is nearly all variance and next to no bias. Why do we care? - we know then that the estimator converges on the correct parameter value as sample size increases.

Comment: Do you see any obvious relation to the Wald-confidence interval?

Comment: @Michael: Given the right regularity conditions, the maximum-likelihood estimator is consistent; I don't know under what conditions the bias is $O(n^{-1})$. A quick look at Lehmann gave me "typically" too.